# How to share SQLite code between cross platform apps?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I asked this question on Xamarin Forms and didn't get a reply which is why I'm posting this here as well. Also I've read the other related questions and I think they don't have the answer which I'm looking for. So I was learning Cross Platform development with Xamarin and unfortunately I can't wrap my head around one thing. Let me explain it in further details below.

I am making a Weather Forecast app which would be running on Android and iOS. Now I know that both platforms natively support SQLite Databases but to take advantage of Xamarin and C# instead of using their native SQLite functionality, I'm going to be using the sqlite-net ORM package. Now, the point where I'm having a conflict with myself is that, Android has SQLiteOpenHelper and ContentProviders. I'm not sure but iOS might have something similar. Now what is the best way to use sqlite-net ORM with these native functionalities so that I can share the basic SQLite code (such as CRUD, etc.) as well as, at the same time make use of essential native functionality such as Android's Content Providers.

On the contrary, If I have to write separate code for managing and querying databases on Android and iOS than are API calls the only thing where I am sharing code? I hope I made myself clear :-)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [Sqlite.Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL). It is the same as SQLite.Net except it works in a PCL. This seems to describe your situation (as you haven't mentioned using MVVMCross). [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL) has a nuget package. I would also check out [SQLiteNetExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLiteNetExtensions/) as it builds on the former and allows you to specify relationships and foreign keys.

With all of you data access in a PCL that is shared by your iOS and Android apps, you have 100% code re-use between platforms and you don't have to worry about different APIs. I haven't heard of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, so I'm not sure what it does or if it is available in these packages, but you might not even need it.

Example use:(taken from their github page)

```cs
var conn = new SQLiteConnection(sqlitePlatform, "foofoo");
var query = conn.Table<Stock>().Where(v => v.Symbol.StartsWith("A"));

foreach (var stock in query)
    Debug.WriteLine("Stock: " + stock.Symbol);
```

You can view a [simple implementation](https://github.com/valdetero/Mymdb/blob/master/Mymdb.Core/DataLayer/LocalDatabase.cs) of the data access that I used. Also, [here](https://github.com/valdetero/Mymdb/blob/master/Mymdb.Shared/ServiceRegistrar.cs) is where you can wire it up with your DI/IoC.

Comment: Seconding valdetero's recommendation. I use the same packages, and the only code specific to platforms is a tiny bit pointing it to the correct file location.

Comment: I'm not sure if one can make Android Content Providers using SQLite.Net-PCL library. And, IMO content providers are a crucial part of any good Android application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the [MVVMCross SQLite Plugin](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/tree/master/SQLite-PCL). It provides native implementations to get instances of `SQLiteConnection` on Android, iOS and Windows.
You can get in on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.SQLitePCL/4.0.0-beta5).

In case you don't know how to get started with MVVMCross, have a look at its [Wiki](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki).

Comment: Let me do that and get back if it's what I wanted or not :-)